# add-migration is empty when I change OnModelCreating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hey everyone I am trying to add one to many many to many cascade delete to OnModelCreating but when I add migration it is empty here is the on model creating that I use to have :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    }
```

And Here is wha I have updated :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

DB is already in use so I cannot just wipe it all or re-migrate.And cant backup and build again because there are too many items and project is in use. When I add migration it just looks like this :

```
public partial class DeleteAll : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

How can I add cascade delete to the project ?

Comment: You're only removing conventions. These won't affect anything that already exists within the entity model. You'll have to update the individual object mappings for classes that already exist within the model.

Comment: is there any way without writing modelBuilder.Entity<Power>()
             .HasRequired(r => r.Member)
             .WithMany()
             .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); this kind of code to everytable ?

Comment: I don't think so as the member will be different for each type. Not sure if there's a way to iterate over mapped entities

Comment: Can you also tell me that should I copy the code as much as foreign key I have ? because with HasRequired(r=>r.Member) I cannot use && to get other foreign keys

Comment: or maybe there is something like add cascadedelete true for evrey foreing key in any table ?

Comment: In all honesty I'm not sure. It's not something I've ever tried to do. Let me see what I can find out.

Comment: I am also searching thank you so much